# Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object

Tags: typescript, mongodb, graphql, nestjs, graphql-js

I am practising nestjs in order to convert ReST API to graphql but I am getting this error whenever I try to fetch data from my GraphQL API using the playground:

> "errors": [
> {
> "message": "Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object",
> "locations": [
> {
> "line": 2,
> "column": 3
> }
> ],
> "path": [
> "lesson"
> ],
> "extensions": {
> "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
> "exception": {
> "stacktrace": [
> "TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object",
> "    at MongoEntityManager. (C:\Users\Oluyinka\Desktop\graphql-mongodb\node_modules\typeorm\entity-manager\MongoEntityManager.js:159:51)",
> "    at step (C:\Users\Oluyinka\Desktop\graphql-mongodb\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:143:27)",
> "    at Object.next (C:\Users\Oluyinka\Desktop\graphql-mongodb\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:124:57)",
> "    at C:\Users\Oluyinka\Desktop\graphql-mongodb\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:117:75",
> "    at new Promise ()",
> "    at Object.__awaiter (C:\Users\Oluyinka\Desktop\graphql-mongodb\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:113:16)",
> "    at MongoEntityManager.findOne (C:\Users\Oluyinka\Desktop\graphql-mongodb\node_modules\typeorm\entity-manager\MongoEntityManager.js:153:24)",
> "    at MongoRepository.findOne (C:\Users\Oluyinka\Desktop\graphql-mongodb\node_modules\typeorm\repository\MongoRepository.js:57:29)",
> "    at LessonService.getLesson (C:\Users\Oluyinka\Desktop\graphql-mongodb\dist\lesson\lesson.service.js:26:44)",
> "    at LessonResolver.lesson (C:\Users\Oluyinka\Desktop\graphql-mongodb\dist\lesson\lesson.resolver.js:24:35)"
> ]
> }
> }
> }   ],   "data": null }

Below is my code:

**lesson.entity.ts**

```
import { Column, Entity, ObjectIdColumn, PrimaryColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class Lesson {
  @ObjectIdColumn()
  _id: string;

  @PrimaryColumn()
  id: string;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column()
  startDate: string;

  @Column()
  endDate: string;
}
```

**lesson.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { Lesson } from './lesson.entity';
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';

@Injectable()
export class LessonService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Lesson) private lessonRepository: Repository<Lesson>,
  ) {}

  async getLesson(id: string): Promise<Lesson> {
    return await this.lessonRepository.findOne({ id });
  }

  async getLessons(): Promise<Lesson[]> {
    return this.lessonRepository.find();
  }

  async createLesson(name, startDate, endDate): Promise<Lesson> {
    const lesson = this.lessonRepository.create({
      id: uuid(),
      name,
      startDate,
      endDate,
    });
    return await this.lessonRepository.save(lesson);
  }
}
```

**lesson.resolver.ts**

```
import { Args, Mutation, Query, Resolver } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { LessonService } from './lesson.service';
import { LessonType } from './lesson.type';

@Resolver((of) => LessonType)
export class LessonResolver {
  constructor(private lessonService: LessonService) {}
  @Query((returns) => LessonType)
  lesson(@Args('id') id: string) {
    return this.lessonService.getLesson(id);
  }

  @Query((returns) => [LessonType])
  lessons() {
    return this.lessonService.getLessons();
  }

  @Mutation((returns) => LessonType)
  createLesson(
    @Args('name') name: string,
    @Args('startDate') startDate: string,
    @Args('endDate') endDate: string,
  ) {
    return this.lessonService.createLesson(name, startDate, endDate);
  }
}
```

**lesson.type.ts**

```
import { Field, ID, ObjectType } from '@nestjs/graphql';

@ObjectType('Lesson')
export class LessonType {
  @Field((type) => ID)
  id: string;

  @Field()
  name: string;

  @Field()
  startDate: string;

  @Field()
  endDate: string;
}
```

Comment: Can you add your Nest package versions?

Comment: Nest CLI Version : 7.6.0

Comment: You have other Nest packages. Please update your question with the requested info

Comment: `[System Information]
OS Version     : Windows 10
NodeJS Version : v14.15.0
YARN Version    : 1.22.10 

[Nest CLI]
Nest CLI Version : 7.6.0

[Nest Platform Information]
platform-express version : 7.6.15
graphql version          : 8.0.2
typeorm version          : 8.0.2
common version           : 7.6.15
core version             : 7.6.15`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like there have been some breaking changes to the MongoDB driver lately. Are you using mongo 4.x?

The issue is likely coming from [here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/src/entity-manager/MongoEntityManager.ts#L175)

You're going to need to pin your mongo version to 3.x until it's supported.

Relevant Github issues:

- https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/7086
- https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/7907#issuecomment-880518853

Answer (score 1):

Your `@nestjs/common`,`@nestjs/core`, and `@nestjs/platform-express` versions are back on major version 7, but you're using `@nestjs/graphql` and `@nestjs/typeorm` are using major version 8. Make sure these major versions are kept in sync, or you'll end up with errors like these.

Also, TypeORM does not support Mongo v4, so make sure you have mongo v3 installed as well, as Jesse mentioned.

---

If I had to guess what happened, you generated a new project using the Nest CLI on v7, then installed the graphql and typeorm packages for Nest which will install the `@latest` of them, v8. I'd suggest upgrading your Nest CLI to version 8 to avoid this in the future.